# Patterns for Multithreaded Network Server in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, network-programming

Are there any templates/patterns/guides I can follow for designing a multithreaded server?  I can't find anything terribly useful online through my google searches.

My program will start a thread to listen for connections using TcpListener.
Every client connection will be handled by it's own IClientHandler thread.  The server will wrap the clientHandler.HandleClient in a delegate, call BeginInvoke, and then quit caring about it.

I also need to be able to cleanly shutdown the listening thread, which is something I'm not finding a lot of exampes of online.

I'm assuming some mix of lock/AutoResetEvents/threading magic combined with the async BeginAceptTcpClient and EndAcceptTcpClient will get me there, but when it comes to networking code, to me it's all been done. So I have to believe there's just some pattern out there I can follow and not get totally confused by the myriad multithreaded corner cases I can never seem to get perfect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oddly enough you may find something on a Computer Science Assignment, [**CSC 512 Programming Assignment 4: Multi-Threaded Server With Patterns**](http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/courses/attic/csc512/assn3.html). Altough it's C++ voodoo but the theory is quite understandable for someone who can do C#.

- [Acceptor/ Connector](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Acc-Con.pdf)
- [Monitor Object](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/monitor.pdf)
- [Thread Safe Interface](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/dispatching.pdf)
- [Wrapper Facade](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/wrapper-facade.pdf)
- [Scoped Locking](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/dispatching.pdf)
- [Strategized Locking](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/locking-patterns.pdf)
- [Reactor](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf)
- [Half Sync/Half-Async](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/PLoP-95.pdf)
- [Leaders/Followers](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/lf.pdf)

Altough you can get the whole list of nice readings on the [main page](http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/courses/attic/csc512/).

Comment: This looks to be very helpful.  Thanks!  Looks like I'll be spending some time reading today.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this previous question:

[How do you minimize the number of threads used in a tcp server application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198/how-do-you-minimize-the-number-of-threads-used-in-a-tcp-server-application)

It's not strictly C# specific, but it has some good advice.